# EditText: how to enable/disable input?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a 7x6 grid of `EditText` views. I want all of them disabled when the application starts, ie they should behave like normal `TextViews` and not to be editable. Then the user taps one cell in the grid, it changes its background and performs something visual. If the user clicks on the cell one more time it should allow editing. I'm struggling with `OnClick()` and `OnFocusChange()` listeners, but I can't accomplish such a basic interaction.

Playing with `setEnabled()` and `setFocusable()` doesn't help. I wonder why even a simple task like this has been made so difficult on Android

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I finally found a solution. It's a matter of calling

- `setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)`
- `setFocusable(boolean)`

when the `EditText` is first created, so it can intercept the clicks. Then one can set those flags back again to make the `EditText` editable, request the focus, and manually show/hide the soft keyboard with `InputMethodManager` methods

Comment: THANK YOU!  I have been experiencing the exact same problem, and this fix works.  Who would've thought that we have to go through this much work (and so little good documentation) to get to such a simple solution?  Good job!

Answer (score 4):

Try using this `setFocusableOnTouch()` instead of `setFocusable()` method.

Comment: I have problem using this. I know it seems a simple task, but actually  it's very difficult to get the work done. I can't explaing you the number of issues when using this, but the interaction is far from my objective. If you have the time, try this on code and see what happens

Answer (score 4):

Firstly write these line in your xml in EditText:

```
android:enabled="false"
```

And than use the code in java as shown below:

```
Boolean check = true;
yourEditText.setEnabled(check);
check=!check;
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting input type to null is not enough, since it only suppress soft keyboard and if device has hardware keyboard, there will be input. So in order to suppress any editing you should do following:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]
    {
        new InputFilter()
        {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend)
            {
                return src.length() < 1 ? dst.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";
            }
        }
    });
```

That will guarantee that `EditText` content won't be changed

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately this isn't enough to solve the problem. It's unbelievable

Comment: What d'u mean unbelievable?! That's not matter of believe or not - it's just matter of checking. I'm using this piece of code in app and it works

Comment: Sorry barmaley: the unbelievable refers to the Android poor documentation, not your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using gridview to achieve your concern you can do the following.

1. setOnItemClicklistener on gridview
2. Extend Edittext to make your own edittext view

The extedned class will contain boolean property named editable using this property in onItemclicklisterner of gridviewyou can call setEditable or setFocusabel or both for a editetext.

If you share your code i can elaborate more on this issue.

Comment: Actually I can't use a GridLayout. I nested two linear layout to make  my table. Also, unfortunately I don't see any setEditable() int the public API

Answer (score -1):

You can do the follwoing:
If you want to make edittext not editable then use following method

```
edittext.setInputtype(Null);
```

If you want to make edittext editable then use the same method and set the proper inputype
visit the [following link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#inputType) for more info

Comment: Doesn't work. The EditText still can get the focus, so it can be edited by a hard keyword. It's a known bug

Answer (score -1):

According the Android guide line please use LongKeyPress for the Question you have" If the user clicks on the cell one more time it should allow editing"

Comment: Where did you read this? I am not aware of these guidelines. Anyway, the problem is not with double tap vs long tap. It's a matter of switching between a TextView and an EditText when use performs an action