# How disable an EditText and keep the background color to be white?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, background-color

When I disable the EditText with `setEnabled(false)` or via the xml file `android:enabled="false"`, the background color will be gray:

[image]

and if I change the background with a white color `android:background="@color/white"`, I will lose the border:

[image]

So my question is, how to disable the EditText (I don't want any dialog to be pooped up on long-clicking on it) and keep the border as it is?

Comment: This answer worked for me (when none of these did):
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7696282/1686442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it:

```
android:editable="false"
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: EditText has no "setEditable"!

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to create your own State List Drawable, and specify the disabled background to be the same as the enabled state.  You would need to create your own 9-Patch image, or you could also pull the resource files from the Android Open Source.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Here's a sample that I use for my EditText backgrounds:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--  Active tab -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_bg_selected" />
    <!--  Inactive tab -->
    <item android:state_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_bg_unselected" />

    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_bg_unselected" />

    <!-- Add all of your other states -->
</selector>
```

You would just need to mess with the different states to create what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `TextView` instead with `android:background="#FFFFFF"`.

you could also try `android:focusable="false"`.