# Using shared preference to save the string and send the saved string as sms to another number

Tags: android

I have to send my own mobile number as sms to another number say xxx i used getLine1number() function it is returning null since it does not have the number stored in the sim.
I am trying to Enter my number save it once using shared preference and send that number as sms to another number.. how it is possible?My code is

```
package com.example.mobile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText editText;
Button saveButton;

String mStoredNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    savePreferences("storedNumber", editText.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Load number and send to phoneNo
            loadSavedPreferences();
            // Now the stored number is in mStoredNumber
            String phoneNo = "123";

            TelephonyManager tManager=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String Imsi=tManager.getSubscriberId();
            String Imei=tManager.getDeviceId();

            try{
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, "IMSI,IMEI and phone number - "+Imsi+","+Imei+","+mStoredNumber+"", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

    loadSavedPreferences();
}
     });
}

private void loadSavedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String number = sharedPreferences.getString("storedNumber", "YourNumber");
    mStoredNumber = number;

    editText.setText(number);
}

private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}
}
```

My xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enter_your_number_" 
    android:inputType="number">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/save"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The number is getting saved and when i again open the application it is not showing the number on the top its again asking for enter the number. And second time when i open the app i should not get the save button.
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: because you are showing number in EditText so use `String phoneNo = editText.getText().toString();` to get number on `button.setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
If you want this to happen without pressing the button, just move the SMS-sending part to onCreate.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editText;
    Button saveButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find editText and saveButton
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Try to send existing number via SMS
        if (sendSMS()) {
            // Successful, exit the app
            finish();
        }

        // If we are here, this means sendSMS returned false 
        // if the phone number was saved before, it is now displayed in editText
        // add an onClickListener to the save button

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Save number and send it
                savePhoneNumber(editText.getText().toString());
                sendSMS();
            }
        });

    }

    /* Sends saved phone number + IMEI, IMSI via SMS, returns true if successful */
    private boolean sendSMS() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String number = sharedPreferences.getString("storedNumber", "");
        if (number == "") {
            // No saved number, ask user to enter it and save it
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter your phone number and tap on Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // There is saved phone number, add it to editText for later use (if SMS sending fails)
            editText.setText(number);
            String phoneNo = "123";
            TelephonyManager tManager=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String Imsi=tManager.getSubscriberId();
            String Imei=tManager.getDeviceId();
            try{
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                String message = "IMSI, IMEI and phone number: "+Imsi+", "+Imei+", "+number;
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS failed, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Stores phone number in the default shared prefs. */
    private void savePhoneNumber(String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("storedNumber", value);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml should contain an EditText (with id = editText1) and a Button (id = button1)

Comment: I am getting error in these two lines Toast.makeText(this, "Saving preference", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   Toast.makeText(this, "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); and if i change it to getapplicationcontext it gets saved and shows saving preference but when i press send its showing as app has unfortunately stopped

Comment: Strange because `this` should be equal to the context in Activity. Anyways did you request the SEND_SMS permission in the Manifest?
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>`

Comment: Yes i added the permission in manifest also even then i get this error.

Comment: Please suggest me a solution when i run the code in android phone i get as app has unfortunately stopped.

Comment: Now it is working... how can i follow the same procedure and i should not have any button save and send but the process should be done. how can i do it? can u please edit it in my program?

Comment: @sheela I've edited the answer, but you still need to Save your phone number for the first time. (Otherwise, if the preference exists, the app sends the SMS and finishes itself.)

Comment: Its ok if it asks for number to save for the first time and again if i open the app it should not ask to save again it should directly send.

Comment: I tried executing the code which you edited it, i don't get any layout its just showing saved and sms sent and "Enter your number" is only sent as sms.

Comment: I am editing the code above when i click save button it gets saved for that instance and its sending sms and again when i open its asking again for the number. Also in the code edited when i open the app second time i should not get the save button how it is possible.

Comment: Are the preference keys all the same? The next time the stored number should be retrieved and the app should only show a toast: SMS Sent!. Can you update the Question with your exact code?

Comment: Actually i updated the code and the code above is the updated one, if it is not possible to open the app second time with the save button, it should ask again for "enter your number" if the imsi of the mobile is changed that is if the sim is changed it should ask for "Enter your number" again if the sim is changed and the user should enter the number again and press save button and the sms should be sent.

Comment: I will post and update my answer to my own question, without using buttons i get enter the number but before entering itself the sms is sent. I am posting the answer. Please see to it and reply.

Comment: Thankyou. It works when i open the app second time the sms is sent without asking for the user to enter the number again but if i change the sim then the number might be different at that time i need to enter the number again, it should ask for the number again but it is not asking the number.. What might be the solution?

Comment: I am editing my answer.. I need to send sms after selecting particular network operator but in my case what is happening is first time when i open the app after selecting the network and entering the number sms is sent after i press save.. but second time when i open the app itself sms is sent without selecting the operator.. What is the solution please reply

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing there are a few errors. But first off, you are sending a hard coded string `"storedNumber"`, instead of getting the string from the `sharedpreferences`/`textbox`.

Change the string you are sending to something dynamic. Like the following - Which loads from textbox.

phoneNo is also hardcoded to `"123"` which seems unrealistic.

```
            String phoneNo = "123";
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, editText.getText().toString(), null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I changed as you said but when i compile the app i get as unfortunately stopped on my android phone.

Comment: @sheela No one can help without knowing what the error is from logcat.

Comment: Actually now its working i can get the number from the user save it and next time when i open the app the number is getting displayed but it is editable but when i open the app for the next time it should not be editable how this could be done?

Comment: @sheela Call `setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`
`setFocusable(false);` inside an if statement, that checks whether the number exist, and if it should be editable or not.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7696282/940834

Comment: how can i follow the same procedure and i should not have any button save and send but the process should be done, it should ask to enter the number and after entering it should save and send automatically. how can i do it? can u please edit it in my program?

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer to include network selection:

```
package com.example.mobnet;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


 EditText editText;
 Button saveButton;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);

    // Find editText and saveButton
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // Try to send existing number via SMS
    if (sendSMS()) {
        // Successful, exit the app
        finish();
    }

    // If we are here, this means sendSMS returned false 
    // if the phone number was saved before, it is now displayed in editText
    // add an onClickListener to the save button

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Save number and send it
            savePhoneNumber(editText.getText().toString());
            sendSMS();
        }
    });

}

/* Sends saved phone number + IMEI, IMSI via SMS, returns true if successful */
private boolean sendSMS() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String number = sharedPreferences.getString("storedNumber", "");
    if (number == "") {
        // No saved number, ask user to enter it and save it
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter your phone number and tap on Save after selecting network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        // There is saved phone number, add it to editText for later use (if SMS sending fails)
        editText.setText(number);
        String phoneNo = "108";
        TelephonyManager tManager=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String Imsi=tManager.getSubscriberId();
        String Imei=tManager.getDeviceId();
        try{
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            String message = "IMSI, IMEI and phone number: "+Imsi+", "+Imei+", "+number;
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS failed, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

/* Stores phone number in the default shared prefs. */
private void savePhoneNumber(String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("storedNumber", value);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: This is conceptually wrong. You need to get the stored phone number in `onCreate`, if it exists: Send the SMS and finish the activity. If it does not exist, show Toast for the user to enter it. Also do not use `editText.onClick` use a separate Button instead. I'll edit my answer to include IMEI/IMSI.

Comment: Thankyou. It works when i open the app second time the sms is sent without asking for the user to enter the number again but if i change the sim then the number might be different at that time i need to enter the number again, it should ask for the number again but it is not asking the number.. What might be the solution?

Comment: That is if the sim card is changed, that is the imsi number is changed at that time it should ask for enter the number again from the user.. plz suggest a solution..

Comment: I did not find the solution yet.. please suggest a solution.