# How to disable all edit texts in anroid app on check of a flag?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created a final submission screen in my app after submission of which I have to show each page readonly, so is there anyway to disable all edit texts in my app ? please help !!

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685280/edittext-how-to-enable-disable-input

Comment: Do you want to do it only for current activity or for the whole App?

Answer (score 1):

after submitting the form set

```
edittext.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug in android..It can be fixed by adding this patch :)
Check these links  [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36907909) and [2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-fixes/source#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flibrary%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

Hope it will be useful.